# Temporary switching to admin store

Tags: event-observer, backend, security, category-products

A client wanted to move products to a different category when sold out so I quickly created an observer but it failed to save the product since frontend wasn't allowed to modifiy the products.

By temporary switching to the admin store and back it would save properly but are there any security conserns by doing this?

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
try {
  $product->save();
} catch ( Exception $e ){
  Mage::logException($e);
}
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
```

Client is using magento 1.8

Comment: Are you sure your conclusion about "front-end not allowed to save products" is not simply the flat tables?

Comment: Not 100% sure but changing to the admin store solved the problem (I don't recall the exact error). As @andrewkett noted this is probably not the best approach and I'm inclined to change it to a cronjob but would still be interested to know if the above solution would be dangerous security-wise. Bear in mind that I'm only been developing for magento a short while and I'm not up to date on the best practices.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at the productAction way of doing things. This doesn't need a full product save.

Then again, moving categories may just be the thing you shouldn't do. This is what a call rowing against the stream.

Ask your client why he wants it in a different category. Sometimes making something appear in another category for all intents and purposes is better then really doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Models that only can be saved or deleted from admin use `Mage::registry('isSecureArea')` to determine if they are in the admin area and show the error message *"Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area"* otherwise ([see Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_protectFromNonAdmin()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php#L506-519))

So you would not need to change the current store, this should be enough:

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
try {
  $product->save();
} catch ( Exception $e ){
  Mage::logException($e);
}
Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
```

The security implications are the same: you have to ask yourself in which way a user could influence the parameters and if this is okay for you. For example, you should never do this after calling `$product->addData()` with user input.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in the frontend code could also negatively affect frontend performance, especially if there are other observers on product save. A better approach might be to write a task that runs periodically through the cron system to move out of stock products.